# Positioning 2 elements on one line with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have page with a grid `col-md-8` and `col-md-4`. What I am trying to achieve is in `col-md-4` section to have two elements (images thumb) on one line then going on the next line/row another two images and so on. The structure of the HTML is the following:

```
<div class="row">    
  <div class="col-md-8">
      <!-- some text here -->
  </div>   
  <div>  
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="tool">
        <img src="image.jpg" style="width:100px; height:75px;"> 
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w3r5jdup/) I am trying to get those 4 small images to the right of the big image and 2x2 on line.

Comment: Your fiddle link isnt working

Comment: Sorry. I've placed the correct link.

Comment: You appear to be missing at least one closing div tag. Can you make sure your example is completely c&p'd?

Comment: Have you tried changing col-md to col-sm?

Comment: You mean like this - http://jsfiddle.net/w3r5jdup/2/

Comment: @Paulie_D this small images under the big need to be on right side of the big and 2 by 2 on the line

Comment: They are...if you widen the viewport....the rest is media queries. Other than that you'd have to provide an image of what this is **supposed** to look like.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. It's like this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following Code

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">    

<div class="col-md-8">
    <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" />
</div>   

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 75px;" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 75px;" />
 </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 75px;" />
             </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 75px;" /> 
             </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We are expecting this to be happen by using Bootstrap.css. have you included your bootstrap.css file?

Comment: It's my bad. Yes, like this. Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you want to position the two images on each line but you can use an approach like this, which is basically, have a `row` for each row of images:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="tool">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 75px;">
                <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 75px;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 75px;">
                <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 75px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could take it further by having each image in a specifically sized `div`, e.g. have each image in a `col-md-6` div rather than both in a `col-md-12` but it depends on what you want to do.

Also, images in bootstrap 3 aren't responsive by default so you'll need to add the `img-responsive` class to all of your images for them to be resized correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your specific case was missing closing divs AND the jsfiddle window was too narrow to respond to col-md-4.

I fixed the closing divs and changed to col-xs-4. You can see the corrected fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/1ezk5oev/

```
<div class="row">    
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" width="200"/>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="tool">
            <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 75px;"/>
                <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 75px;"/>
                <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 75px;"/>
                <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 75px;"/>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will solve your issue. You also will want to replace your styling with `class='img-responsive'` if you want your images to change their size respectively.

```
<div class="row">    
<div class="col-md-8">
    <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg"/>
</div>   
<div>  
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="tool">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                 <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally find using tables for something like this the best way to go. If you like it as well, use this example:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="tool">
                <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 75px;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="tool">
                <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 75px;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="tool">
                <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 75px;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="tool">
                <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/4Vln8-640x428.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 75px;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>                    
</tr>
```

Code can also be found at: http://jsfiddle.net/9se6Lep0/